# Add objects with Industry Compatible Keymap

Tags: modeling

Whats the hotkey for Adding mesh using *Industry Compatible keymap*?

I know *Blender keymap* is <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>  but not sure about the *Industry Compatible keymap*

Or if anyone could link me how to add hotkey to the *Add Mesh* operator would be good too.

Comment: It doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

In Blender 2.83 go to *Edit -> Preferences -> Keymap*

On top, instead of *Industry Compatible*, temporarily change it to *Blender*.

Go to *3D View -> Object Mode -> Object Mode (Global) -> Add*
Copy  `wm.call_menu`  and  `VIEW3D_MT_add`

On top change back to *Industry Compatible*
again go to *3D View -> Object Mode -> Object Mode (Global)* but now push *Add New* at the bottom.

After, click on *none* change *none* for `wm.call_menu`.

Active the key <kbd>Shift</kbd> and in the *Name* field enter `VIEW3D_MT_add`

Next time you will know how to do it for any key

Comment: Tips: _for instance if you want shading menu or..._ go to preference Change on top the Keymap Configuration to **Blender**, Active _Key-Binding_ and search for **Z**, click on Shading Take note of the Category : `Object Mode`, the menu: `wm.call_menu_pie` and the Name : ` VIEW3D_MT_shading_pie` and add it in **Industry Compatible**.